# Returning multiple non-Objective C objects/variables from method

Tags: objective-c, methods, global-variables, nsdictionary

I know NSDictionary can be used to return multiple things from a method when all the objects are Objective C type objects, but is there a way to package objects that are non-Objective C?

I have a method that I need to return an int and an IplImage. Without converting the IplImage to a NSValue (which I do not know how to do and wish to avoid), can I return 2 items from a method?

Also note that this method is defined in a separate class from which it is being called, thus I don't think I can use a class variable to store the int (or maybe I can?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this approach will work for simple cases, i am sure you have seen it:

```
- (BOOL)caclulate:(NSError**)outError;
```

it returns a `BOOL` and an `NSError`.

To return an `int`:

```
- (BOOL)caclulate:(int*)outInt;
```

Using that approach, you can declare your method like this:

```
- (int)calculate:(IplImage*)outImage;
```

and then the caller's code takes the following form:

```
IplImage outImage;
int result = [object calculate:&outImage];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so where is the IplImage returned?

Answer (score 1):

If `NSError**` solution doesn't work for you, you might want to create a helper `struct` that holds both the `int` and `IplImage`:

```
typedef struct _Data {
    int num;
    IplImage image;
} Data;
```

and then pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

The common way is what you described, using a NSDictionary.  Unfortunately, that means working with NSValue for non-standard types (NSNumber, etc).

Or you could use in/out params similar to the way most methods work with NSError.